# Babel & JSX Browser Code Highlighting

Tags: babeljs, reactjs, static-site, codehighlighter

I use https://highlightjs.org/ for an in browser (and in a static site generator) to highlight code snippets for blogs and sites.  I'm almost certain its not handling ES6, ES7, JSX, and Flow.

How can I get better highlighting for these new additions to javascript?

Please advise.  Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried to contact https://twitter.com/highlightjs? Why haven't you?

Comment: From what I can gather from chatter on github and other places, open source authors prefer questions to be asked on stack overflow.  Github is for collaboration on issues, and twitter is isn't a support channel.  I could be wrong, but I think its best form to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using highlight.js you can register languages.

```html
<script src="/js/highlight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/highlight-js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/highlight-xml.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  hljs.registerLanguage('js', H_js);
  hljs.registerLanguage('xml', H_xml);
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>
```

Here is a good [hightlight-js.js](https://gist.github.com/jrhicks/193cfa7a1046179ea6f7) for ES6/React.